# how to take screenshot with GIMP under Wayland (Jammy)

Tags: 22.04, gimp

Since I started using Jammy (22.04), if I use gimp screenshot, it returns a black screen.

I understand that the issue is in relation with wayland which limit access between software for more safety.

**Is there a solution?**
Or should I use default screen-shot (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25587225/6614155)

I saw similar issue for visio-conf : https://askubuntu.com/a/1339294/385361

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always change from Wayland to Xorg by logging out, pressing the setting icon on the bottom right, selecting `Ubuntu on Xorg`, and logging back in.

If there is a reason why you want to use Wayland, you should definitely use the default screenshot (GNOME-Screenshot).

I don't get why you want to use a screenshot built with gimp, not its built-in application.

If you don't want to use gnome-screenshot you can always get an alternative like Flameshot or Kazam - those are two really good ways to take a screenshot, and they both work in Wayland.

*Hope this helped you in a way and good luck!*

Comment: thank you. I appreciate to take screenshot with Gimp because in many case, I crop/resize … after shot. Right now I switch to Xorg.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but there is also an amazing screenshot app called Ksnip (https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip) which is really great for quick photo editing right after a screenshot capture. I would try it, since it works on Xorg, Wayland and the rest.
*P.S. Do you think you could mark my question above as "answered"?*

Comment: Say what you want about Wayland, but it has a lot going for it. No tearing, better hdpi support, better multimonitor support, etc. _Surely_ there must be a solution to this? Screen recorders, screenshot apps like Gimp and Flameshot, video conferencing applications etc can't all be "obsolete"?

Comment: Flameshot isn't working on Ubuntu 22.04.4. See their massive issues list in GitHub. And GIMP screenshots appear black for me, too.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure to which issue exactly you are referencing to on the Flameshot GitHub page. How about you try using Flameshot on either Wayland or Xorg and see which works. Also maybe you can try using another great screenshot app that I mentioned above that allows a quick-crop and editing called Ksnip.

Comment: E.g. there are many issues like this: https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/3498 Flameshot on earlier versions of Ubuntu worked well for me, though. I think I tried Ksnip in the past but preferred Flameshot. I'll try Ksnip again soon. Thanks.