# Has anyone actually managed to use Zoom screen share on Wayland (strictly no X11)?

Tags: 22.04, firefox, google-chrome, wayland, zoom-meeting

Zoom app doesn't support Wayland yet and it is necessary to use X11 instead. It's been months since Zoom mentioned they are working on fixing this issue.

```
System : Ubuntu 22.04
Zoom version : 5.15.7.6521
Firefox version : 116.0.3
```

Zoom is provided by my company for regular meeting, so using other meeting platforms is not an option. What I've tried :

1. **X11** : I'm not looking to switch to X11. My system works so badly with it, very slow and constant lagging when performing any task, while Wayland has been very smooth, no lag, I have been enjoying it very much. I tried to switch to X11 to test if Zoom screen share would work, it did work. But for some random shenanigans in my system, it took me nearly 3 hours to switch back to Wayland and GDM3. I do not want to switch to X11 again, especially only for Zoom.
2. **Reinstall from Debian package**. A particular thread in Zoom community (I forgot to save the link) suggested to purge Zoom from Ubuntu and reinstall the Debian version, seemed to work for a select few people. But doesn't solve the issue for most people, including me.
3. Running Zoom with `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME` following [this](https://community.zoom.com/t5/Meetings/Wayland-screen-sharing-broken-with-GNOME-41-on-Fedora-35/m-p/67334/highlight/true#M35903) from Zoom Community.
4. Running Zoom with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb`
5. **Firefox** Pipewire :

   - Pipewire installed :

     ```
      gstreamer1.0-pipewire/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
      libpipewire-0.3-0/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
      libpipewire-0.3-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 all [installed]
      libpipewire-0.3-modules/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
      pipewire-bin/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
      pipewire-media-session/jammy,now 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
      pipewire/jammy-updates,now 0.3.48-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
     ```
   - Have it enabled in Firefox.
   - Setting `enableWaylandShare` to true from `~/.config/zoomus.conf` following [this instruction from Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Zoom_Meetings). Screen sharing via browser still not working.
   - From [a July 2023 thread on Zoom community](https://community.zoom.com/t5/Meetings/Screen-Sharing-Broken-with-5-14-10-on-Linux-KDE-Plasma-Wayland/m-p/126522/highlight/true#M72056) : From Zoom desktop client --> Settings --> Share Screen --> Advanced --> Change screen capture to Pipewire. Screen sharing via desktop app still not working.
   - Webrtc screen sharing showing no option of windows we can share from the drop down menu. With the default option, when I click share nothing happens. WebRTC and Firefox permissions Look like this :

[image]
[image]

6. **Chrome** Pipewire :

   - `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` enabled following [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293394/screen-sharing-under-wayland).
   - When sharing screen, chrome always crashes. Here's the error log :

     ```
      libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)  
      [46896:46896:0826/083601.699022:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(702)] Message 0 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost  
      [OpenH264] this = 0x0x2e20050e0120, Warning:bEnableFrameSkip = 0,bitrate can't be controlled for RC_QUALITY_MODE,RC_BITRATE_MODE and RC_TIMESTAMP_MODE without enabling skip frame.
      [47042:16:0826/083604.321188:ERROR:dtls_transport.cc(133)] DtlsTransport in connected state has incomplete TLS information
      [47042:16:0826/083604.321689:ERROR:dtls_srtp_transport.cc(215)] No DTLS-SRTP selected crypto suite[47042:16:0826/083604.344151:ERROR:dtls_transport.cc(133)] DtlsTransport in connected state has incomplete TLS information
      [47042:16:0826/083604.344273:ERROR:dtls_srtp_transport.cc(215)] No DTLS-SRTP selected crypto suiteINFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
      [46938:46938:0826/083617.066264:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times
      [46896:47267:0826/083617.222097:ERROR:egl_dmabuf.cc(632)] Failed to bind DMA buf framebuffer
      [46896:47267:0826/083617.222261:ERROR:shared_screencast_stream.cc(940)] Dropping DMA-BUF modifier: 72057594037927935 and trying to renegotiate stream parameters
      [46896:47267:0826/083617.225915:ERROR:egl_dmabuf.cc(632)] Failed to bind DMA buf framebuffer
      [46896:47267:0826/083617.226040:ERROR:shared_screencast_stream.cc(940)] Dropping DMA-BUF modifier: 72057594037927935 and trying to renegotiate stream parameters[0826/083617.243325:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
      [1]46896 segmentation fault (core dumped)  google-chrome
     ```

     `libva` error ? Here's installed `libva` in my system :

     ```
      libva-dev/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libva-drm2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libva-drm2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
      libva-glx2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libva-glx2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
      libva-wayland2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libva-x11-2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libva-x11-2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
      libva2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libva2/jammy,now 2.14.0-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
      libvala-0.56-0/jammy,now 0.56.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libvala-0.56-dev/jammy,now 0.56.0-1 amd64 [installed]
      libvalacodegen-0.56-0/jammy,now 0.56.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
      libvalapanel0/jammy,now 0.5.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
      libvamp-hostsdk3v5/jammy,now 2.10.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
      libvariable-magic-perl/jammy,now 0.62-1build5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
     ```

Any other suggestions I can try to make Zoom screen sharing work in Wayland ? Fyi as of now, I use VMware for any Zoom meeting where I need to share screen, this too, is not optimal but the only way to go for me.

*ps: I posted this question on another community platform before with no working soution yet.*

**[Update Oct 2023]**
Following a comment from @Dan Eisenhut, recently I've updated Firefox and sharing screen via browser is confirmed to be working now. On the other hand, I've updated Zoom app as well and share screen showing just a black screen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, after initially having problems in a meeting where I needed it, I have now solved this by installing `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` using:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

After that a restart is needed.

This is my setup:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- GNOME 42.9
- Wayland
- `pipewire` 0.3.48-1ubuntu3
- `xdg-desktop-portal` 1.14.4-1ubuntu2
- `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` 42.1-0buntu1 (this is what was missing, I only had `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`)

It works in Firefox web browser (FF 117.0.1) and desktop app (5.16.1).

Comment: Hi, thanks Rob. I just checked my system, apparently I have `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` installed already, therefore the problem remains the same. But it gave me insights to the right direction, I might need to check the desktop libraries after all.

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I came here with the same issue trying to share my full screen in MS Teams.  I already had xdg-desktop-portal-gnome installed.  But I was using Google Chrome.  Based on this answer, I tried in Firefox and it worked fine.  So time to migrate over to Firefox.

Comment: @DanEisenhut, thanks ! I've updated my Firefox recently, I can confirm as well that share screen via browser is working now. I'll update my question to add this information. Share screen via app still doesnt work for me though, just showing a black screen.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful, for unknown reason, the apt clean up everything and cause the screenshare stop working... And this helps me to make it wworking again. I lost all xdg-desktop-portal* package in 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe Zoom works in pure Wayland for screen sharing.   I have been trying to do it for two years or more, and no version has ever, ever, worked.  The best result has been that the screen is shared, but then you cannot stop sharing the screen without ending the call/meeting entirely, because the controls do not display longer than about five seconds.

Everyone who said that Zoom screen sharing under Wayland worked for them, provided I was able to get them to test it carefully, has discovered that they were actually running Zoom under XWayland but were unaware of it.

Have you managed to run zoom screen sharing using XWayland?  It more or less works okay for me.  This is adequate for now at least.